# Why JDK doesn't provide IGE block cipher mode

Tags: java, encryption, java-security

The JDK provides various block cipher modes implementations, e.g. CBC, CTR, ECB.
As per title, is there a (maybe documented somewhere) reason why IGE mode is not provided?

Comment: The same reason pretty much anything is absent: because they can't be expected to provide everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java contains a lot of cryptography for a *standard runtime*. However, it is pretty clear that it is still mainly driven by standards, and particularly TLS / X.509. It is pretty easy to see this: key stores used to only store (RSA) private keys with their chains attached. The default certificate store contains all the necessary root certificates etc.

There are a few more well known block ciphers and modes implemented for secret key encryption. However, these are all modes **standardized by NIST** and included in most libraries. It doesn't include many other ciphers or modes. Including a mode that has been specifically designed for a niche purpose such as IGE doesn't make sense. Although IGE and specifically bi-IGE make some sense in schemes providing *plausible deniability* their error propagation properties are kind of lost in the days of authenticated encryption. See also [this question and answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9395/1172) (note the person asking the question).

However, nothing is preventing you to create one in a provider, and define your own mode that way. Note that you may need to sign that provider if you want to include it with specific commercial releases of Java.